# CM4 custom board with max98357

Tags: adafruit

I had this module on my raspberry CM4 IO board:
Adafruit MAX98357 I2S Class-D Mono Amp
The module works perfectly on my IO board, but when I made my board (see diagram) it just keeps on grunting when I boot the CM module and if I turn on e.g. music via mplayer the speaker stops grunting and is silent, if I turn off the music it just grunts again. I can't seem to get it to work.
I did the installation using this guide:https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/raspberry-pi-usage
Thank you for your advice
[image: schematic]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there had been some manufacturing error with your own board. Try to troubleshoot your PCB. See if there is a short circuit. Test with a multimeter.